# python, how the "x" change its value in the code

Tags: python

```
a = 100
x = 1000
def myFun(a,b):
    x = b-a
    return x 

a = myFun(a,x)
x = myFun(a,x)
print(x+a)
```

I know in first function, `a = myFun(a,x)` is `900`, but why is the result of `x = myFun(a,x)` ,`100`?

Comment: Why should it not return 100? You passed in `a` (900) and `x` (the global, not the local, unchanged at 1000).

Answer (score 3):

The name `x` inside the function `myFunc()` is *independent* from the global name `x`. They live in different namespaces.

As such, when you call `myFunc(a, x)` the first time, the global `x` value is unchanged; it remains `1000`:

```
>>> a = 100
>>> x = 1000
>>> def myFun(a,b):
...     x = b-a
...     return x 
... 
>>> myFun(a,x)
900
>>> x
1000
```

If you wanted the global `x` to change when calling `myFunc()`, you need to tell Python *explicitly* that `x` is to be treated as a global in the function:

```
def myFun(a,b):
    global x
    x = b-a
    return x
```

Now assigning to `x` in the function will set the global name `x`:

```
>>> a = 100
>>> x = 1000
>>> def myFun(a,b):
...     global x
...     x = b-a
...     return x 
... 
>>> myFun(a,x)
900
>>> x
900
```